# JCarousel multiple rows

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement two rows rather than one in the JCarousel module in Drupal. I have tried hacking the module, but only achieve some level of success thanks to some codes online. The problem I have is separating the first row from the second, the current situation is they are joined together so they look like one column. Below is the code. I use wrapper divs and applied padding and margins but no success. Maybe someone with a bit more knowledge could assist me.
     ">

```
<?php $i=0; $rows_number=2; //you can change the number of rows ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
<?php if($i%$rows_number==0) : ?>
<li class="<?php print $row_classes[$id]; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="one-item">
<?php print $row; ?>
</div>
<?php if($i%$rows_number==($rows_number-1)) : ?>
</li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php if($i%$rows_number!=0) : ?>
</li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```